# INDEX and MATCH : value not on the first column, formula returning #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this kind of Excel file:

```
A    | B    | C          | D    | E    | ... | Z
S1   | INT  | 25/06/2019 | Tom  | 1002 | ... | myFormula
S1   | CLO  | 26/08/2020 | Tho  | 1002 | ... | myFormula
S1   | UNA  | 13/11/2019 | Nath | 1003 | ... | myFormula
S1   | REJ  | 14/04/2021 | Lee  | 1005 | ... | myFormula 
S1   | INT  | 17/08/2018 | Joh  | 1005 | ... | myFormula
```

I would like to get content of column C if B and E are matching specific value. So I'm trying to use `=INDEX(C2:C65000;MATCH(E2;E2:E65000;FALSE);MATCH("INT";B2:B65000;FALSE))` to get `25/06/2019` in `Z2`.

Or `=INDEX(C2:C65000;MATCH(E6;E2:E65000;FALSE);MATCH("INT";B2:B65000;FALSE))` to get `17/08/2018` in `Z6`.

However, formula is returning `#N/A`.

Did you already faced this behavior ?

Thank you

Regards

Comment: Your second match argument will index the column number, while what you're trying to get is a match for both arguments. This can be accomplished by an array formula, however you're referencing the matching cell to it's own range, so the result will always be the row you're searching in (if Excel doesn't error). What is the purpose of your formula?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to get the date in the column C if the column B contains `INT`. At the end, I need to do calculation based on this date. So, this is just a intermediary step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `INDEX/MATCH` like-

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH(E2&"INT",$E$2:$E$6&$B$2:$B$6,0))
```

You may need to array entry `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for non `O365` version of excel.

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then can try `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(1,($E$2:$E$6=E2)*($B$2:$B$6="INT"),$C$2:$C$6)
```

[image]

Comment: However XLOOKUP is very slow (my file has more than 20000 rows) ... Any idea why ?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could combine the search values and ranges with index-match. I always use `match(1,(condtion1)*(condition2),0)`. Nice to learn different approaches.